# Can I run 8 4 bulb fluorescent fixtures only on one breaker?

Tags: electrical

Electrical  would 14 gauge wire 15amp breaker or should I use 12 gauge wire with a 20 amp breaker. It’s just lights only!

Comment: What size are the lamps? 4' T8, T5. There are different wattages. If it was me I would be going with LED's. LED's draw less than half the wattage and provide more light. 32w x 8 x 4 is just over 1000w so it could be done if 32w t8

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the fixture you are referring to is something like a 2X4 layin or surface mount fixture with 4' fluorescent lamps. We used to use a rule of thumb of 200W per fixture. So 200*4 = 1600W or 13 1/3A if you voltage is 120V. These fixtures also need to be calculated as continuous duty or a circuit can only be loaded to 80%. A 15A circuit can only handle 12A worth of this type of load which means a 15A circuit can't handle your load. You can use a 20A circuit which would handle 16A of this type of load. That is what I would recommend.

If you still want to investigate using a 15A circuit, we would need more information on your fixture such as lamp and ballast type.

Comment: I would expect an electrician to ask the type of lamps, rule of thumb means nothing! A t5 fixture would draw over 200w per fixture and a t8 would be much lower.

Comment: @EdBeal - The 200W is a hand-grenade. In other words it gets us close when we really don't have enough information. So what your really trying to do is to find out id the 15A is to small and looking at the quick calc you can see that it is to close to really take the risk. Whereas a 20A fits just fine. So for the minimal extra cost you just go with the 20A circuit. That may not even be how an electrician thinks but it is exactly how an electrical contractor thinks. The less liability the better and looking at the minimal cost this decision is easy.

Answer (score 1):

### It really depends on the *power factor* of your ballasts

On a 15A circuit, your "budget" for continuous load is 1440 watts, or to be more precise, 1440 **VA**.  This gives you a budget of 180VA per lamp, or 1.5 amps.

Watts is the power you are billed for.  VA is the power the wires must carry.   As such, the wire rating is contingent on VA, not watts.  Fluorescent and LED conversions (especially cheap LEDs) often a much higher VA than watts.   This must be watched closely.

The difference between VA and watts is because power is AC (*alternating* current) - electronic loads behave oddly as the voltage changes, for instance  a rectifier draws only when the AC waveform is near its peak. So it draws higher current(amps) during peak than its actual usage (watts) would imply, and we must provide wire for that.  Its A (amp) rating accurately reflects that peak, as does VA.

So there is no substitute here for either looking for labeling on the fixture, or popping the cover off a fixture and looking for the ballasts (there may be two) and adding up the listed amps or VA.

We can't guess because even if you know the tubes, ballasts differ in how hard they drive the tubes (ballast factor) and can vary *substantially* in power factor.

if your ballasts are beyond spec, you should be able to change ballasts to others that will be within spec.  If called for, you can upgrade to T8 ballsts and tubes at this time, or direct-Wire LED.  However, beware: the "cheapie" LEDs found on Amazon Marketplace and the bottom shelf of your favorite store are of dubious origin, and the A and VA numbers are certainly a lie.

Answer (score 0):

200W x 4 = 800w which is easy for a 15A x 110v = 1650W capable circuit.

200W seems quite high though fir a ballast. The last 2 bulb ballast I removed was 55W.

led might be better still. [https://www.amazon.com/garages-Daylight-Ceiling-Wrapround-Worklight/dp/B078B7KG1R/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078B7KG1R)